# Object of type 'WebElement' has no len() - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether an element exists, and if it does, checks whether that element is numeric or not, etc. However, trying to do `len` or `.size()` on the elements throws an error. Any safe way for me to check whether an element exists? This is a snippet:

```
groupId = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(groupIdCSS)
    if len(groupId)>0:
        if any (c.isalpha() for c in groupId.text):
            deletegroup = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(5) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ml-3.px-2.elevation-0.v-card.v-sheet.theme--light > div > div.col-md-4.col-12 > div > div > button')
            deletegroup.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            kback = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > div > div')
            kback.click()
            htree = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.row.no-gutters.align-start.justify-start.align-content-start > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.v-slide-group__wrapper > div > div:nth-child(3)')
            htree.click()
            time.sleep(2)
    else:
        kback = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > div > div')
        kback.click()
        htree = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.row.no-gutters.align-start.justify-start.align-content-start > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.v-slide-group__wrapper > div > div:nth-child(3)')
        htree.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(groupIdCSS)
```

this returns a single web element. In Selenium-Python `len()` - for single web element is not allowed. That's the reason you are getting the mentioned error  :

> WebElement has no len()

but this

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(groupIdCSS)
```

returns a list of web element.

change that, and then you can easily do :

```
if len(groupId) > 0 :
```

and instead of

```
if any (c.isalpha() for c in groupId.text):
```

you should do :

```
for a in groupId:
    if a.text == "some value"
```

Comment: That however, gives me this: `'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. Basically, it won't run my isalpha() on a list. Do I just target the first element of the list or?

Comment: groupId is a list,  and .text in not allowed on list in Python

Comment: or you can just remove .text from there and try again